# How to model this in DDD and repository pattern

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, repository, polymorphism, strategy-pattern

I want to model service like this

```
public class FooService
{
    public GetById(ISecurityContext context, id)
    {
        //checking context has right to view
        //calling Foo repository to getById
    }

    public Add(ISecurityContext context,Foo fooEntity)
    {
        //checking context has right to add
        //calling Foo repository to add
    }



}
```

In the above methods i want to pass different type of SecurityContext 
So what i have did is

```
Public Interface ISecurityContext
{

}

UsernamePasswordContext : ISecurityContext
{
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Password { get;set; }

}

SessionContext : ISecurityContext
{
   public string SessionId {get ; set;}
}
```

So In my Account Service i have a method

```
public class AccountService
{
    public Account GetAccountFromSecurityContext(ISecurityContext context)
    {
        if(context is UsernamePasswordContext)
            return GetAccountByUsernamePassword(context.Username,context.Password);
        else if (context is SessionContext)
            return GetAccountBySessionId(context.SessionId);

        // more else if for different type of context
    }


}
```

In the above code i didnt liked so many if else
So i tried introducing polymorphism

So in my ISecurityContext interface i added a GetAccount method which all sub class will implement

```
Public Interface ISecurityContext
{
     Account GetAccount();
}


UsernamePasswordContext : ISecurityContext
{
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Password { get;set; }

   public Account GetAccount()
   {
       //call account service 
       GetAccountByUsernamePassword(this.Username,this.Password);
   }


}
```

and my account service will become like this

```
public class AccountService
{
    public Account GetAccountFromSecurityContext(ISecurityContext context)
    {
       context.GetAccount();
    }   

}
```

But the problem here is that i am calling a service/repository from my UsernamePasswordContext POCO which voilates DDD

So what are other ways i can model this scenario.

Comment: I think you were on the right line when you added the account service and used that to generate the account based on the context though I'd probably use a factory to generate the account based on the context type

Comment: ok, but that factory will require reference to repository which will again violate DDD

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Do you consider `UsernamePasswordContext` an entity from your domain? The example your giving suggests you are trying to put your logic in services and repositories. A more DDD approach would put most of your logic in your domain model (which you might already be doing but your example is confusing to me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not far off from the solution. In this case, I would inject a factory into your `AccountService` that would take on the responsibility of the `if..then..else`. Then, the factory could use one of many possible solutions.

One change I would make right off is I would make your AccountService implement an interface which should make it easier to inject later. Assuming you're using some IOC container, you shouldn't have to worry too much about dependencies because you're letting the container handle all that.

Here are the pieces you already had, with some minor ajustments:

```
public class Account
{
    //some account information and behavior
}

public interface ISecurityContext
{
}

public class UsernamePasswordContext : ISecurityContext
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class SessionContext : ISecurityContext
{
    public string SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

Here's your account service along with it's implementation:

```
public interface IAccountService
{
    Account GetAccountFromSecurityContext(ISecurityContext securityContext);
}

public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
    readonly IAccountFactory _accountFactory;

    public AccountService(IAccountFactory accountFactory)
    {
        _accountFactory = accountFactory;
    }

    public Account GetAccountFromSecurityContext(ISecurityContext securityContext)
    {
        Account account = _accountFactory.Create(securityContext);
        return account;
    }
}
```

So, you can see here that I've injected an `IAccountFactory` that will handle the actual creation (retrieval, whatever) of the `Account` object. All we care about at this point is that the account gets created/retrieved... we don't care about how.

---

There are a few ways you can implement a factory like this. One way is to use a type of strategy pattern where you have a list of widgets that know how to resolve an account. Then you just pick the widget (strategy) that matches and execute it. Something similar to this would be a factory that uses an IOC or service locator to resolve a type that has been registered previously in application configuration.

In the way of an example, here's one possible implementation of `IAccountFactory` using `CommonServiceLocator`:

```
public interface IAccountFactory
{
    Account Create(ISecurityContext securityContext);
}

public class ServiceLocatorAccountFactory : IAccountFactory
{
    readonly IServiceLocator _serviceLocator;

    public ServiceLocatorAccountFactory(IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
    {
        _serviceLocator = serviceLocator;
    }

    public Account Create(ISecurityContext securityContext)
    {
        var resolverType = typeof (IAccountResolver<>).MakeGenericType(securityContext.GetType());            
        dynamic resolver = _serviceLocator.GetInstance(resolverType);
        return resolver.Resolve(securityContext);
    }
}
```

My factory here goes out to the service locator context and grabs whatever resolver matches our security context. Here are a couple examples of possible resolvers:

```
public interface IAccountResolver<in TSecurityContext> where TSecurityContext : ISecurityContext
{
    Account Resolve(TSecurityContext securityContext);
}

public class UsernamePasswordAccountResolver : IAccountResolver<UsernamePasswordContext>
{
    readonly IRepository _repository;

    public UsernamePasswordAccountResolver(IRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public Account Resolve(UsernamePasswordContext securityContext)
    {
        var account = _repository.GetByUsernameAndPassword(securityContext.Username,
                                                           securityContext.Password);

        return account;
    }
}

public class SessionAccountResolver : IAccountResolver<SessionContext>
{
    public Account Resolve(SessionContext securityContext)
    {
        //get the account using the session information
        return someAccount;
    }
}
```

The only thing left is to register the resolvers in your IOC container so that they can be found when the service locator tries to resolve them in the factory.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Can you show me the implementation of _serviceLocator.GetInstance(resolverType);  That would be really great...

Comment: The implementation of GetInstance is inside the CommonServiceLocator library by Microsoft (http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/). CommonServiceLocator is basically an adapter to whatever IOC container you plan to use.

Comment: Is there any name of the pattern which you showed above. I want to edit the title accordingly

Comment: Well definitely we're using the Factory Pattern here. Not sure if we might be using the Strategy Pattern inside the factory to get the account type. Someone else might be able to comment on that.